# Bootstrap ui Collapse is open as default

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm having a problem with bootstrap ui collapsed directive, It show open as default and I needed collapsed on page load,  I'm setting the variables correctly but still doesn't work correctly

here's part of my code:

```
aside class="col-md-3 leftSidebar separator-right" ng-controller="Collapse as vm">
<div class="row separator">
    <div class="sidebarPosition">
        <div class="leftSidebar__toggle">
            <a class="mod" ng-click="vm.isCollapsedLeft = !vm.isCollapsedLeft"><span class="fa fa-bars"></span> Outline</a>

            <ul uib-collapse="vm.isCollapsedLeft">
                <li><a href="#scientific_abstract" du-smooth-scroll>Scientific Abstract</a></li>
                <li><a href="#layperson_abstract" du-smooth-scroll>Layperson’s Abstract</a></li>
                <li><a href="#introduction" du-smooth-scroll>Introduction</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Results</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Discussion</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Methods</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Additional Information</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Change History</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Acknowledgements</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Author Information</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Author Contributions</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row leftSidebar__sections">
    <ul>
        <li><a ui-sref="article.figures"><span class="fa fa-picture-o"></span> Figures</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="article.references"><span class="fa fa-link"></span> References</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-retweet"></span> Related</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"> <span class="fa fa-area-chart"></span> Stats Impact</a>
        </li>
        <li><a ui-sref="article.comments"><span class="fa fa-comment"></span> Comments</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</aside>
```

my Controller:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.bootstrap')
    .controller('Collapse', Collapse);

function Collapse() {

    var vm = this;

    vm.isCollapsedLeft = false;
    vm.isCollapsedRight = false;

}

})();
```

and here's a plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/D0vFMEQe4a2GT1yJLTLk?p=preview

Thanks for the help.

Comment: plunkr working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you want it to be collapsed on page load, but you are setting `vm.isCollapsedLeft = false;`. Set `vm.isCollapsedLeft = true;` and it will be collapsed on page load.

Comment: You're right, I tried that but it was not working, I feel stupid, hahaha

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html >
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style class="cp-pen-styles">.panel-heading .accordion-toggle:after {
    /* symbol for "opening" panels */
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';  /* essential for enabling glyphicon */
    content: "\e114";    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
    float: left;        /* adjust as needed */
    color: grey;         /* adjust as needed */
}
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
    /* symbol for "collapsed" panels */
    content: "\e080";    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">

  
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" aria-multiselectable="true" >
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"  href="#collapseOne" >
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"  href="#collapseTwo" >
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in" >
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse in" >
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
  
</div> <!-- end container -->

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body></html>
```